# How to manipulate the decimals in an integer? CS50 Luhn's Algorithm

Tags: c, cs50, luhn

I want to add all the digits of an array and get the sum from them. The thing i'm struggling with is I have to multiply the numbers I get from my input by which makes an array have the possibility of two digits in one array. 
An example number would be 8346761. 
The challenge wants me to take every other digit (6,6,3), then multiply them (12,12,6) and add the first digits together like (1+2+1+2+6)=12. I only know how to do 12+12+6=30 and was looking for help on this specific part. 
I'm new to programming and also stack overflow so if there is anything I did wrong asking the question please tell me so I can fix it. Thank you

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    long long cardNum = get_long_long("What is your credit card number?\n");


    printf("Number: %lld\n", cardNum);
    long long cardNumz = cardNum; 


    long long Multnumbers[20];
    cardNum /= 10;
    for (long long i=0; i < 20; i++) 
    {

        Multnumbers[i] = cardNum % 10;
        Multnumbers[i] *= 2;
        cardNum /= 100;

    }
    int sum = 0;

    int loop;
    for(loop = 0; loop < 20; loop++)
    {

      printf("%lld ", Multnumbers[loop]);

    }
     printf("\n");

    long long number=Multnumbers[0];
    for (long long rz=1;rz<11;rz++)
    {
        number = number*10+Multnumbers[rz];
    }
    printf("Big multiple number is %lld\n ", number);


 long long Nonmultnumbers[20];

    for (long long i=0; i < 20; i++) 
    {

        Nonmultnumbers[i] = cardNumz % 10;
        cardNumz /= 100;

    }
    int loopn;
    for(loopn = 0; loopn < 20; loopn++)

      printf("Non multnumbers%lld ", Nonmultnumbers[loopn]);
    printf("\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to take digits (1 and 2) in two digit number (12) to calculate sum. Easiest way might be dividing these numbers with 10 to calculate first digit. And using remainder operator to calculate second digits.

Calculation of first digit. (This division won't give 1.2 as long as numbers are integers).

```
int n = 12 / 10 // n will be 1 (1st digit).
```

Calculation of second digit. Using remainder operator, `%`.

```
int rem = 12 % 10 // rem will be 2 (2nd digit).
```